# Camel exception/error handling transacted route without causing client exception

Tags: java, error-handling, apache-camel, transactional

I am working with a command-event driven system using JMS and Apache Camel for for routing. In the following situation:

- I send the system a request-reply command "X".
- The system receives "X" via a transacted camel route.
- While processing "X" the system sends out several events, "Y" & "Z",
  but as its part of the transacted route these should not be flushed
  until the transaction has completed.
- An runtime exception occurs - which should cause the transaction to
  rollback.

I want to be able to intercept the exception and reply with a genuine message (rather than exception) to the client. As such I started to implement an error handler:

```
    onException(RuntimeException.class)
        .handled(true)
        .markRollbackOnly()
        .filter(header(Header.REPLY_TO.getName()).isNotNull())
        .to(DESTINATION_FOR_EXCEPTION_HANDLING)
        .to(DESTINATION_FOR_REPLIES);
```

Where:

- DESTINATION_FOR_EXCEPTION_HANDLING is a bean that takes the exception and returns a message object
- DESTINATION_FOR_REPLIES is a bean that sets the out body to the message object

The problem I have is that if I include "markRollbackOnly()" it:

- Prevents "Y" & "Z" from being flushed - GOOD
- Causes an exchange exception on the client making the requestReply - BAD

And If i don't include it, then:

- "Y" & "Z" get flushed - BAD
- I receive the genuine message object on the client - GOOD

How can I configure camel to both prevent the flushing of messages in the transaction, and yet be able to convert the exception to a handled error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried Claus approach but couldn't get it to work for some reason, I must have misunderstood or setup something incorrectly.

Eventually I solved this by propagating a second transaction internally, one the error handler I could then "markRollbackOnlyLast" the second transaction, but respond with a "good" message on the primary transaction:

```
    TransactionTemplate newTransactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(platformTransactionManager);
    newTransactionTemplate.setPropagationBehavior(PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
    Policy requireNewTransaction = new SpringTransactionPolicy(newTransactionTemplate);

    onException(RuntimeException.class)
        .onWhen(header(Header.REPLY_TO.getName()).isNotNull())
            .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, EXCEPTION_STACKTRACE)
            .to(PROCESSOR_FOR_EXCEPTION_HANDLING)
            .to(PROCESSOR_FOR_REPLY)
            .handled(true)
            .markRollbackOnlyLast();

    from(FROM)
        .policy(requireNewTransaction)...
```

Answer (score 0):

If the onException sending to those 2 destinations are using the same Camel component as the from, then you would need to use a separate component for that so they are indpendent. As the rollback would otherwise cause them all to rollback.

Assuming you use ActiveMQ, you just declare two components

```
   <bean id="activemq" ...>

   <bean id="activemq2" ...>
```

And then use activemq2 in the onException. Then can be configured to use the same brokerUrl and all that. And for the 2nd you may need to set it to transacted=false.

Comment: Would that not still cause an exception on the client, as the original component will still respond with the exchange exception?